# Where did Skrull Phil Coulson get a gun?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

The skrulls can shape-shift to use parts of their bodies to form solid hand-weapons (as extensions), but how did the Skrull impersonating Coulson get a human gun - which he allegedly could use and can actually drop?

From [the Wikia article on Skrulls](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deviant_Skrulls):

> When they imitate an inorganic object, they take on its appearance, but not its properties.

[image: Skrull with human gun]

Comment: It was LA in the 90s. You could get a gun free with a six pack of Crystal Pepsi.

Comment: Golden rule: *Do not trust everything you find on Wiki*

Answer (score 3):

Unknown where exactly he got it from but the Skrulls has been on Earth for a while at this point. To the point where this one in particular had managed to slip in alongside Fury as Coulson without anyone else noticing. It’s not implausible for the Skrull to have gotten a pistol from any number of sources: a store, stolen from someone, pinched off another officer or even got it out of the glovebox in the car. Most important cars for agents would have pistols hidden away in them in case they lose their personal one.

In short it doesn’t really matter where or how he got it though. It’s not important to the story and it would have been odd for him not to have one whilst disguised as Coulson.

FWIW the Skrull impersonating Coulson appears as Fury is interrogating Vers at the phone before the other Skrull shoots from the rooftop. We know this because there’s a small time skip from Coulson talking to the security guard and then approaching Vers. In that time, Coulson would have entered the Blockbuster, and whilst in there the Skrull took his place and approaches from behind Fury during the conversation. This same Skrull as Coulson is the one that gets in the car with Fury.

Answer (score 1):

Playing the scene below at 0,25 speed, I'm not entirely sure Skrull-Coulson actually made that weapon. He *seems* to take it out of his jacket, sure, but as we didn't have eyes on him all the time he could as well have grabbed it from, say, the glove compartment; fits with the person he's impersonating, to be prepared to fire during a chase.

If there's anywhere in the Marvel universe I'd look for a gun it's in Nick Fury's car.

Comment: It would be very un-Nick-Fury-like to have a passenger take a gun from Fury's glovebox without Nick Fury noticing.

Comment: @VogonPoet on the one hand, yes - on the other hand, you could argue that there's a combination of the situation being unprecedented (aliens!), Fury being young (though not a noob), and Skrull-Coulson having some experience.

Comment: Who’s saying he didn’t notice Skrull Coulson get the gun out if it was in there? It’s not like he’s complain about his colleague being prepared.

Comment: We could argue anything at all but not without discussion. Was this Skrull impersonating Coulson for a long time? Or does he just keep a human gun handy for emergencies? I tried following that particular Skrull back to see where he came from - difficult

Comment: @VogonPoet I added an update to my answer for when the Skrull Coulson appears.